# Не видит SSD во время установки Windows после Linux / Ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

При загрузки с загрузочной флешки, мастер установки не выводит список логических дисков для форматирования.

На ноутбуке установлена Ubuntu. На одном же SSD Windows и Ubuntu работать не будут, поэтому хочу вернуться обратно на Windows.

[image: Фото с ошибкой]

Как бы мне отформатировать диск для переустановки? Знаю, что заезженная тема. Но не получается найти решение.

Я так понимаю, что физическое извлечение диска из ноутбука и последующее его форматирование отдельно, поможет решить проблему. Но не хотелось бы лезть внутрь ноутбука. Там миллион разных болтиков. Это тот ещё геморрой собрать всё обратно))

P.S.:

Пытался найти какие-то отдельные драйвера для Ubuntu под ноутбук, имеющими отношение к SSD. Ничего такого не нашёл.

На разных форумах написано, что последние версии Ubuntu автоматически устанавливают нужные драйвера, как это делает Windows 10.

Comment: "На одном же SSD Windows и Ubuntu работать не будут" - неправда, будут

Comment: Я так понял, что будет конфликт ОС из-за разной разметки диска. Если бы они работали вместе и я мог бы просто переключаться между ними - это было бы вообще очень круто.

Comment: Ничто не мешает поставить разные ОС на разные разделы диска и установить загрузчик, который умеет загружать разные ОС (например grub)

Comment: Вангую, что винда не видит ссд просто потому что в дистрибутиве нет дров на контроллер винта твоего ноута.

Comment: Попробую поискать драйвера...

Comment: скорее всего windows установлена как uefi, а линукс устанавливается как через bios. И поэтому не будет видеть. В биосе нужно аккуратно отключить secure boot. Ещё раз - аккуратно.

Answer (score 0):

Поделюсь опытом: когда на одном диске стояла Windows и Ubuntu, то Windows не позволяла своими системными средствами отформатировать раздел с Ubuntu, однако она его видела.
Здесь же у вас компьютер вообще не показывает существующие диски. Интернет подсказал, что такое возможно, если у вас один из свежих процессоров intel.
Также интернет подсказал следующий алгоритм по решению проблемы (в конце прикрепила ссылку на первоисточник):

- заранее скачайте необходимые драйвера,
- разархивируйте их и закиньте на загрузочную флешку,
- в момент установки винды выберите опцию "загрузить"
- найдите нужный драйвер (TGL)
  Диски должны появиться. [Первоисточник на инструкцию](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptsHVHnGfwE&ab_channel=IzzyLaif)

Answer (score 0):

При установке Windows на компьютерах с UEFI с помощью программы установки Windows стиль раздела жесткого диска должен быть настроен для поддержки режима UEFI или устаревшей версии режима совместимости с BIOS.
 Если диск не видно, значит стили не совпадают,  это связано с тем, что компьютер загружен в режиме UEFI, но жесткий диск не настроен для режима UEFI. У вас есть несколько вариантов:

1. Перезагрузите компьютер в устаревшем режиме совместимости с BIOS. Этот вариант позволяет сохранить существующий стиль раздела.
2. Настройте диск для UEFI с помощью стиля раздела GPT.  Можно с загрузочного устроуства, удалить все разделы или переделать с MBR в GPT.

Разбирать ничего не нужно.